# Tabs Affecting Compilation of SWeave Code

Tags: formatting, sweave, winedt

The following SWeave code, compiled using WinEdt 8.1 with the [Sweave plugin](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/R-Sweave.php) produces a nice R image:

```
\begin{figure}
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
set.seed(123)
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y)
@
\caption{sweave test}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I add a tab to keep the content between the figure delimiters organized, which is standard practice in a very large document I am editing, the figure comes out as garbled text:

```
\begin{figure}
    <<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
    set.seed(123)
    x <- 1:10
    y <- rnorm(10)
    plot(x, y)
    @
    \caption{sweave test}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Garbled text]

If anyone has any ideas why this is happening and how one can incorporate tabs into SWeave content I would be very grateful.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Sweave User Manual:

> Code chunks start with `<<name>>=` **at the beginning of a line**

That is, inserting a tab you are violating this elemental convention, and simply the R chunk is not recognized as R code, but as plain LaTeX text.

This can sound inconvenient, but imagine than you want to show (not execute) verbatim some R chunk  in your .Rnw:

```
\begin{verbatim}
  <<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
    set.seed(1213)
    x <- 1:10
    y <- rnorm(10)
    plot(x, y)
  @
\end{verbatim}
```

But then this text is recognized as a true R chunk just as:

```
\begin{verbatim}
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
    set.seed(1213)
    x <- 1:10
    y <- rnorm(10)
    plot(x, y)
@
\end{verbatim}
```

Fortunately, only in the  second case is a true R chunk and you will obtain  the verbatim text "`\includegraphics{somename-001}`" instead of the R  code.

For the readability of the .Rnw file you still can add tabs inside the code of the R chunk, or add LaTeX comments before or after the chunk, or R comments inside the chunk, or blank lines... but not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the note about the << needing to be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @JHowIX FYI, [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr) allows white spaces before `<<`

Comment: @Yihui But knitr is not longer compatible with  Sweave-specific syntax, so first the .Rnw fole  must be converted with `Sweave2knitr`. Behind this, because knitr allows white spaces, you cannot compile the code of my answer as plain LaTeX. May be this feature is not a good idea.

Comment: @Fran It is possible to compile a code chunk literally (without interpreting it as an R code chunk), which is FAQ 8: http://bit.ly/knitr-faq From my side, there is no point sticking to the Sweave-specific syntax, since it is much less flexible and sometimes confusing (e.g. `true` vs `TRUE`). Just a personal opinion, and not surprisingly, very biased :)

Comment: @Yihui, Yes, it is possible, also a  simple \begin{verbatim}<< without carriage return solve the problem, but the existence of a FAQ for this demonstrates that is a problem (more than one advantage, IMHO). With respect to the Sweave syntax, yes it is less flexible, but the important point is that now is incompatible and the user must be aware of that to avoid headaches (for example, if one want reuse documents made for Sweave with knitr).

Comment: @Fran No, it is not an advantage, but it is very rare that one wants to write a literal code chunk, so this normally does not hurt. From all the feedback I have received so far, the headache of the incompatibility rarely becomes a real problem, and for the very few users who came from Sweave, they were happy to use `Sweave2knitr()` once and never went back, so I'm not terribly worried about it. Again, from what I have seen, it is more surprising to users that indenting a code chunk makes it fail to work than continuing to work.