# Probsoln & Sweave

Tags: sweave, probsoln

I just started learning the probsoln package so I can create problem sets. I have a basic example that is working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\showanswers

\begin{document}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{showanswers}}{\textbf{Solution Sheet}}{\textbf{Homework problems}}

  \loadallproblems{HW_Descriptive.rnw}

  \useproblem{comparing_rates1}
\end{document}
```

where the problem set HW_Descriptive.rnw contains

```
\begin{defproblem}{comparing_rates1}
  If 136,670,000 persons were wage and salary workers and 10,544,000 persons were self-employed, what is the fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers for each group? 
\begin{onlysolution}%
  \begin{solution}
  Wage and salary workers have a fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers of 136670000/100000 =  1366.7
  Self-employed workers have a fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers of  10544000/100000 = 105.44
  \end{solution}
\end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}
```

What I would like to do is include R code into the problems (sometimes in the question, most often in the solution). Unfortunately the most direct approach of

```
\begin{defproblem}{comparing_rates2}
If 136,670,000 persons were wage and salary workers and 10,544,000 persons were self-employed, what is the fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers for each group? 
\begin{onlysolution}%
    \begin{solution}
    <<>>=
    136670000/100000
    10544000/100000
    @
    \end{solution}
\end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}
```

Did not work, the output looking like

**Solution:** !!??=136670000/100000 10544000/100000 @

Can anyone point me to a working example of Sweave + probsol?

Comment: I hate promoting [my own package](http://yihui.name/knitr), but alas, this problem just keeps on surprising users... See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199015/tabs-affecting-compilation-of-sweave-code

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I was not aware of the space issue before <<>>. However even after I move it back it's not resolving properly and I don't  `\useproblem{comparing_rates1}` resolve at all in the .tex file, and there's no errors in the log. How else can I troubleshoot this to find the error? Would the probsoln package be rewriting my code and inserting a tab? Again, if so how can I find it?

And trust me @Yihui , I tried very very hard to write my course notes in knitr before I started, but I was unable to get answers to questions I had, that I knew how to do/able to find in Sweave.

Comment: @Yihui - Side note. I am using knitr not Sweave. Rstudio has everything so pre-packaged and behind the scenes I forgot I switched my weaving program default to knitr a while ago.
It was Markdown that I gave up on. Way more comfortable in Latex. Sorry for the confusion/mistake on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `probsoln`. If you try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    <<>>=
    136670000/100000
    10544000/100000
    @
\end{document}
```

You get

[image: ¡¡¿¿=136670000/10000010544000/100000@]

This is just the default behaviour of LaTeX with the default fonts.

You can use verbatim within a problem definition if you use the `fragile` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\showanswers

\begin{defproblem}{comparing_rates2}[fragile]
If 136,670,000 persons were wage and salary workers and 10,544,000 persons were self-employed, what is the fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers for each group? 
\begin{onlysolution}[fragile]%
    \begin{solution}
\begin{verbatim}
    <<>>=
    136670000/100000
    10544000/100000
    @
\end{verbatim}
    \end{solution}
\end{onlysolution}
\end{defproblem}

\begin{document}

  \ifthenelse{\boolean{showanswers}}{\textbf{Solution Sheet}}{\textbf{Homework problems}}


  \useproblem{comparing_rates2}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Alternatively, you could try using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Comment: Thanks @Nicola , the [fragile] worked, the verbatim part didn't. So a combination of moving the <<>> back to the left margin and adding [fragile]. Perfect thanks!