# fragile/verbatim R code inside probsoln when using an exterior Rnw file for the data sets

Tags: r, knitr, probsoln

A follow-up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200033/probsoln-sweave) about using R code inside the environments used in `probsoln` package. If you uncomment out the section below and define the problem within the main Rnw file, the R code is compiled and presented correctly.
However, when you move that problem definition to a separate file and \load it in, the R code no longer is passed correctly.
I know the original answer from the previous thread had a verbatim environment around the R code, but I was unable to get that to work, the fragile option was what allowed it to work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\showanswers

%%% -- Problem Definition --%%
% \begin{defproblem}{comparing_rates2}[fragile]
% If 136,670,000 persons were wage and salary workers and 10,544,000 persons were self-employed, what is the fatal injury rate per 100,000 workers for each group? 
% 
% \begin{onlysolution}[fragile]%
%     \begin{solution}
%     \begin{enumerate}
%   \item Wage and salary workers have a fatal injury rate of 3.4 per 100,000 workers. \\
%   Self-employed workers have a fatal injury rate of 9.9 per 100,000 workers. 
%   \item Self-employed workers have the worst outcome becuase they show a higher rate of fatal injury. 
% \end{enumerate} 
% <<>>=
% (4613/136670000)*100000
% (1044/10544000)*100000
% @
%     \end{solution}
% \end{onlysolution}
% \end{defproblem}

%% - Load all problems defined in the dataset
\loadallproblems{test_dataset.rnw}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{showanswers}}{\title{Solution set for Week 1 HW}}{\title{Homework for Week 1 HW}}
\maketitle 

\paragraph{Problem set 1.1: Comparing Rates}
  \useproblem{comparing_rates2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Nicola, I am getting exactly your output when I use your code. 
The problem lies in that this piece of code:

```
<<>>=
(4613/136670000)*100000
(1044/10544000)*100000
@
```

Should be compiled as R code and not simple verbatim text. So the verbatim wrapper around this chunk is making it so it's not being passed to the `knitr` compiler as R code to be processed.

[UPDATE] -- This made me think about how Rstudio handles multiple *.Rnw files being stitched together and I realized that the \loadallproblems that is used in `probsoln` doesn't work with knitr, and that I had to use

```
<<test_dataset,child="test_dataset.Rnw">>=
@
```

instead to call in the code that's in the test_dataset, and put the corresponding

```
% !Rnw root = test.Rnw
<<set-parent, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
set_parent('test.Rnw')
@
```

in the child file. Totally a case of 
http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you just wanted the code typeset. I didn't realise you wanted the R code compiled.