# Incorporating R code in problem sheets of probsoln

Tags: r, sweave, probsoln

While working with the `probsoln` package, how can I include R code in problem sheets?

My main document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln, verbatim}
\PSNrandseed{200}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{enumerate}
\selectrandomly{sum.tex}{1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and the example in worksheet is something like this ,

```
\newproblem{dfp:sum}{% <<echo=FALSE>>= n<-100:999 y<-sample(n,8) s<-y[1]+y[2] @ Add the numbers \Sexpr{y[1]} and \Sexpr{y[2]} }{% sum is \Sexpr{s} }
```

Comment: Does [fragile/verbatim R code inside probsoln when using an exterior Rnw file for the data sets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200380) help?

Comment: Thank you Mr Nicola Talbot, but by using fragile/verbatim R code You just get the code, but i want the code to be compiled. My main document is \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln, verbatim}
\PSNrandseed{200}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{enumerate}
\selectrandomly{exR.tex}{1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Comment: Thank you Mr Nicola Talbot, but by using fragile/verbatim R code You just get the code, but i want the code to be compiled. My main document is \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{probsoln, verbatim}
\PSNrandseed{200}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{enumerate}
\selectrandomly{sum.tex}{1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document} and the example in worksheet is something like this , \newproblem{dfp:sum}{%
<<echo=FALSE>>=
n<-100:999
y<-sample(n,8)
s<-y[1]+y[2]
@
Add the numbers \Sexpr{y[1]} and \Sexpr{y[2]}
}{%
sum  is \Sexpr{s}
} Sorry i am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: I've copied your code to your question for clarity. I'm sorry, I've never used R, but perhaps someone else can help. (p.s. I'm not a Mr, just use @ followed by the user name to notify.)

Comment: i am still working on the problem. Meanwhile no one has offered any suggestion. Is it really a very trivial question or is it badly phrased?

Comment: It's not a trivial question. It needs someone with experience using sweave. I've changed the tags which may attract the attention of sweave users.